# Form doesn't post with tinymce activated

Tags: javascript, jquery, forms, tinymce

I have added timymce to a textarea but when active it does not post, I mean, clicking the submit button does nothing. While desabling tinymce the form works just fine... probably there is something lacking, but I can not find what....
Here's my code:

```
....
        <script src="../libs/tinymce/js/tinymce/tinymce.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
        <script>
tinymce.init({
  selector: 'textarea#pagebody',
  language: 'ca',
  theme: 'modern',
  content_css: '/mnt/vmdata/iac/web/css/CQPweb-yellow.css',
  autoresize_min_height: 350,
  autoresize_bottom_margin: 30,
  plugins: 'advlist autoresize charmap colorpicker emoticons help imagetools legacyoutput media pagebreak print spellchecker template toc wordcount anchor autosave code contextmenu fullpage hr importcss link nonbreaking paste save tabfocus textcolor visualblocks autolink bbcode codesample directionality fullscreen image insertdatetime lists noneditable preview searchreplace table textpattern visualchars',
  toolbar1: 'formatselect | searchreplace bold italic strikethrough forecolor backcolor | link anchor | alignleft aligncenter alignright alignjustify outdent indent pagebreak | numlist bullist table hr | removeformat code charmap insertdatetime codesample fullpage fullscreen preview | image media | help',
  image_advtab: true,
  images_upload_url: 'postAcceptor.php',
  images_upload_base_path: '',
  images_upload_credentials: true
 });
        </script>

</head>
<body>
<form name="documentation" action="createpage.php" method="post">
<p><select size="1" name="corpusname" required>
<option style="font-size: 95%;" value="">Select corpus</option>
<?php
$result = mysqli_query($dbiac, "SELECT * FROM corpus_info") or die(mysqli_error($dbiac));
while($corpus = mysqli_fetch_array($result)){
echo "<option style='font-size: 95%;' value='".$corpus['corpus']."'>".$corpus['title']."</option>";
}
?>
</select></p>
<p><textarea name='pagebody' id='pagebody' rows='60' required></textarea></p>
<p><input type='submit' value='Create page' /></p>
</form>
.....
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is almost unbelievable, but the "tiny" thing that was preventing the form to be posted was the "required" attribute at the **textarea** tag, so taking it out solved the problem!